# Certain actions in Terminal.app in OS X cause noise in audio/video streaming

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, video-streaming, audio-streaming

If I'm listening to something in Pandora or YouTube, and I'm in Terminal.app in OS X 10.7.5, if I use the up arrow to scroll through bash command history, then that works fine with no noises. But, if I scroll down past the last command in bash history with the down key, it makes a noise (somewhat the noise that is made when plugging an instrument cable into an amplifier). I've also noticed that some other actions will cause a similar noise, but I don't remember what they are at the moment.

Any idea what is causing this or if there is a fix?

Comment: I'd guess it's the terminal bell: check the preferences for your terminal application to turn off the sound

Comment: Awesome! That was it! Repost that as an answer, and I'll accept it. Thanks!